# Update Z values on a line feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I'm using ArcMap 10.1 with Info License. Here is my issue. I have a section of track line with incorrect Z values applied. There are over 15,000 vertexes that I need to update all at once. I know I can do it manually but that would take forever. Basically I just need to add 2 ft. to the existing Z values.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have 3d analyst?

Comment: I think you should be able to do this using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor() - look into the @SHAPE* token examples.

Answer (score 4):

This can be a bit tricky with polylines as the z-values of each vertice are not immediately accessible through the shape field. You will need to access the polyline geometry object (Shape field) with `SHAPE@` and drill down further to get to each point in the polyline geometry. Here is a `python` and `arcpy` code snippet for how to access the z-values of the vertices of a specific line in a polyline feature class.

```
id_field = 'TARGET_FID' #field identifies which features need to be shifted
id_value = 12 #value in id_field that identifies specific feature that needs to be shifted
shift_value = 2
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Breaklines", ['SHAPE@', id_field]) as u_cur:
    for row in u_cur:
        if row[1] == id_value:
            geometry = row[0]
            pts = geom.getPart(0) #get polyline geometry
            pt_array = arcpy.Array() #create array to house new points
            for pt in pts:
                pt.Z += shift_value #shift z value
                pt_array.add(pt) #add point to array
            new_polyline_geometry = arcpy.Polyline(pt_array, None, True) #important to enable z-value by having the third parameter set to True
            row[0] = new_polyline_geometry #set row[0] which is SHAPE@ (geometry object)
            u_cur.updateRow(row)
```

In a nut shell:

- loop over the vertices of the polyline geometry
- update each z value of the point geometry
- add the updated point to an array
- once all points in the polyline have been adjusted:

  - create a new polyline geometry with the point array, making sure to set it to z-enabled
  - then update the old polyline geometry with the newly created geometry

Currently this will only work on the first part of the geometry, see `pts = geom.getPart(0)`, however it can be easily edited to work on the line if it has multiple parts. By updating the code and integrating another loop and using the `.partCount` of the `Polyline` object.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`, you can access and edit Z-values with `'SHAPE@Z'`. Key though, is to use `explode_to_points` argument; this allows you to cycle through the vertices without having to deal with geometry and array objects.

*Required word of caution: arcpy.da.UpdateCursor of course updates your data. Work on a copy of your original data.*

```py
fc = "path to fc"
z_increase = 2

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, 'SHAPE@Z', explode_to_points=True) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow([row[0] + z_increase])
```

Answer (score 2):

Block:

```py
def plineZ(shp):
 arr=arcpy.Array();pM=arcpy.Point()
 part=shp.getPart(0);n=len(part)
 for i in xrange(n):
  p=part.getObject(i)
  pM.X=p.X;pM.Y=p.Y;pM.Z=p.Z+2*0.33
  arr.add(pM)
 return arcpy.Polyline(arr)
```

Expression:

plineZ( !Shape! )

Run it on Shape field using backup copy of feature class. Works for single part polylines only