# Update Z values of polygon veritices with multiparts and donuts

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

I am trying to update Z values of the vertices of the polygon shape. The script bellow works for polygons without multiparts and donuts. If I run this script for polygon shape that contains multiparts and donuts, I get error. How can I make it work?

My script:

```
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\Scratch\fcTest.shp"

# Get Spatial Reference of dataset
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
sr = desc.spatialReference

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:

        # Get Geometry
        geom = row[0]

        # Create an empty array object
        arr = arcpy.Array()

        # Read points, if Z is found to be zero reset it to 1
        for part in geom:
            for pnt in part:
                if not pnt:
                    arr.add(None)
                    continue

                if pnt.Z == 0:
                    pnt.Z = 1.0

                 # Add updated point to Array
                arr.add(pnt)

        # Construct new polygon geometry from array whilst setting spatial reference and indicating it has Z
        newpoly = arcpy.Polygon(arr,sr,True)

        #Update row
        cursor.updateRow([newpoly])
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Scratch\fcTest.py", line 21, in <module>
    if pnt.Z == 0:
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Z'
   >>>
```

Comment: @Vince i tried my best but i think i am doing some thing wrong in the loop. its erasing all gaps/donuts in the polygons. is it possible for you to amend the script?

Comment: I'm not going to fix this script when I already fixed the other. If you have questions, they should be on code that correctly handles the None between subparts, which it the fundamental issue in the answer.

Comment: I amended the script what you mentioned above, but its not working  in this case. Hope you can undestand my problem. see amended script above

Comment: Your error is incompatible with the code. If you update one you need to update the other.

Comment: yes, you are correct. now i dont have error but i am getting het polygons without multiparts/donuts. This is not what i expect, and more over i dont know how to update the other.

Comment: In the future, please do not post errors that are not generated by the code provided; if you change the code, you ***must*** change the rest of the question to match. You now have two identical questions with two different accepted answers, which is going to cost a moderator effort to clean up.

Comment: @Vince,thank you,  i think there is some misunderstanding. In my opinion i have two different questions. It must be strange if i ask the same question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to give the `explode_to_points` if the [`UpdateCursror`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) a try in this case.

If you set it to `True`, each row of your cursor will be each vertex of your polygons.

I did not tested it, but you can try something like the below:

```
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\Scratch\fcTest.shp"

# Get Spatial Reference of dataset
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
sr = desc.spatialReference

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@Z"], explode_to_points=True) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == 0:
            row[0] = 1.0
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: While returning multiple rows per feature in a `SearchCursor` can make some sense, in an `UpdateCursor` it seems insane -- Wouldn't this corrupt the geometry on `updateRow`? Actually, with the `shape@Z`, an update shouldn't be possible at all.

Comment: @umbe 1987, your method is good for 0 values and for lines. but for polygons if i increase with values 2, the first vertex is getting 4.

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem. I solved a similar problem in the past. Here is the link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/177380/9518.

Comment: Sorry just fixed an issue in the code.

Comment: @Ram I don't get your point, sorry. Can you explain? I just adapted your code to work with explode_to_points.

Comment: @Vince also, explode_to_points is a parameter of the UpdateCursror method, so I think it should be there for a reason. But I'm not saying you're wrong, it would be very interesting also for me to know if this would lead to a corrupted geometry.

Comment: @umbe 1987 sorry, it was my mistake. i just tried, your method is working  thank you

Comment: @umbe 1987, your [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177289/updating-z-coordinates-of-points-in-polylines/177380#177380) i tried to use your code for polygons if i increase with values 2, the first vertex is getting 4 and rest is 2.  Can you look after it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96854/discussion-between-ram-and-umbe1987).

Comment: @umbe1987  This can corrupt the geometry, but it's subtle -- The closing point is modified to match each starting point, so any iterative calculation (z = z + N) is executed *twice* for each start/end point in a polygon (e.g., starting with `POLYGON Z (( 0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 1 0, 0 1 0, 0 0 0))` and calculating `shape@Z` to `row[0] = row[0] + 1` results in `POLYGON Z (( 0 0 2, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 2))`

Comment: @Vince I just gave an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/330898/9518) which explain how I would handle this. It does not seeems related to the use of `explode_to_points=True` though, rather to how ArcPy handles Polygon vertices (which IMHO seems quite wrong to me anyway).